# is it possible to keep button with fixed position after zoom in or zoom out on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, pinchzoom

I am working on website having fixed position button it works fine on desktop but can it possible to keep button on fixed position after zoom in or zoom out on mobile device.
or can reposition button on zoom in or zoom out.

```
CSS:

.exit {
    text-align:center;
}

.exit.btn{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
}

HTML:

 <div class="exit">
     <a href="/" class="btn btn-blue">Exit</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up like this:

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-6 text-center">
<div class="exit">
     <a href="/" class="btn btn-blue">Exit</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This will make sure the div that is holding the button will stay while you change your screen size.